# Firebird: Alter table and create stored procedure from out C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, alter-table, firebird2.1

I'm trying to create a stored procedure from out C# into Firebird 2.1.
The code is:

```
String sql = @"EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN " +
    "ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE ALTER FIELD1 TYPE Char(50); " +
    "SET TERM ^ ; CREATE PROCEDURE name ( input_parameter_name < datatype>, ... )" + 
    "RETURNS ( output_parameter_name < datatype>, ... ) AS DECLARE VARIABLE variable_name < datatype>;" +
    "BEGIN /* write your code here */ END^ SET TERM ; ^" + 
    " END";

    public int Execute(string sql)
    {
        int result = 0;

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            FbTransaction transaction = Fbconnection.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                FbCommand command = new FbCommand(sql, Fbconnection, transaction);
                int rc = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = rc;
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                globals.logfile.log(e.ToString());
                globals.logfile.flush();
                result = 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The error message given is:

> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005):
>   Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 24 ALTER

Must be something small, but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL is not allowed in PSQL (stored procedures, triggers, execute block), so executing an `ALTER TABLE` like this is rejected.

Also `SET TERM` is not part of the Firebird statement syntax. It is specific to query tools like isql and FlameRobin, as they use statement terminators like `;` to know when they end of a statement is reached and can be sent to the server. When executing PSQL blocks those tools need to watch for a different statement terminator to prevent them from sending incomplete statements to the server. In the actual Firebird statement syntax `;` is only part of PSQL blocks.

You will need to execute the `ALTER TABLE` and the `CREATE PROCEDURE` separately without an `EXECUTE BLOCK`.

Comment: Hi Mark, took me a while to get back to this, but I've tested it, and it works fine.

Thanks again for your help.